# sizes and arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays

i'm following cLearnthehardway at exercise 8 the following code was written , i have 2 questions

- while printing and integers it used %ld to print them not %d !!
- while printing areas[10]//out of range it printed 0! why didn't it show me an error while it does by valgrind(6erros)

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

int areas[]={10,12,13,14,20};
char name[]="Zed";
char full_name[]={'Z','e','d',' ','A','.',' ','S','h','a','w','\0'};

printf("The size of an int: %ld\n", sizeof(int));//why didn't we use %d instead of %ld(*)
printf("The size of areas (int[]):%ld\n",sizeof(areas));//*
printf("The number of ints in areas : %ld\n",sizeof(areas)/sizeof(int));//*
printf("The first area is %d, the second area is %d\n",areas[0],areas[1]);//Printed areas[10]=0!!
printf("The size of a char is: %ld\n",sizeof(char));//*
printf("The size of name(char[]) is:%ld\n",sizeof(name));//*
printf("The number of chars is : %ld\n",sizeof(name)/sizeof(char));//*
printf("the size of FULL NAME  (char[]) is:%ld\n",sizeof(full_name));//*
printf("The number of chars in full name is %ld\n",sizeof(full_name)/sizeof(char));//*
printf("name=\"%s\" and full name =\"%s\"\n",name,full_name);// what is \"%s\" \ is an    ESCAPE


return 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem had been solved by answers and i chose the perfect one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `sizeof` returns value of type `size_t`. Usually `size_t` is defined as `unsigned long` (though it can be any unsigned integral type). According to the C Standard `sizeof( long )` is greater than or equal to `sizeof( int )`. For example `sizeof( long )` can be equal to 8 while `sizeof( int )` can be equal to 4. So in the code you showed format specifier `%ld` is used to output an object of type `long int` though it would be better to use `%zu` where flag `z` means that an object of type size_t will be outputed.

As for arrays then the compiler does not check boundaries of arrays. It is the programmer who shall correctly specify indices of array elements.

Answer (score 0):

About printing sizes: `sizeof(int)` is of integral type `size_t`. On some machines that type is the same as `unsigned int`, on other machines it is the same as `unsigned long`. In practice the size is a small integer, so you can code

```
 printf("The size of an int: %d\n", (int) sizeof(int));
```

Pedantically you could `#include <inttypes.h>` and use some formats (e.g. `%zu`) there.

About out-of-range indexes, they cause a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) at runtime (which *may* SEGV). This an example of [**undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Always **avoid it**. Here are [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of horrors which could happen on UB.

Comment: It is strange to be called "bro", You are probably younger than most of my children (I have 6 grand-children & 4 children, 3 of them beings adults & working...).

Comment: yes u right , my apologies sir :)